# Fetch tables using codeigniter issue, database

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, fetch

Im trying to run my program that i made in php but in this case i wanna run it using codeigniter.

i've been trying to fetch the tables without success, this is my old code:

```
    <?php include('connect.php'); 

?>

<html>
<head>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>
    <body>

    <div class="container"> 
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">



    <a href="estudiante.php"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success">AGREGAR</button></a><br /><br />
        <h2 align="center">TABLA:MATERIAS</h2>
        <input id="busqueda_tabla" type="text">
            <table class="table table-hover" align="center" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="700" id="tabla_busqueda">
                <thead>
                    <th>id</th>
                    <th>Carrera</th>
                    <th>Nombre</th>
                    <th>Descripcion</th>
                    <th>Carga horaria (hs)</th>
                    <th>Accion</th>
                </thead>

    <?php

                $sql=mysql_query("SELECT s.*, c.nombre AS carrera FROM materias s LEFT JOIN carreras c ON s.carrera_id=c.id");
                $i=1;
                    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
                        echo "<tr>
                                <td>".$i."</td>
                                <td>".$row['carrera']."</td>
                                <td>".$row['nombre']."</td>
                                <td>".$row['descripcion']."</td>
                                <td>".$row['carga_horaria']."</td>
                                <td align='center'>
                                    <a href='editar.php?editar=1&iden=".$row['id']."'><button type='button' class='btn btn-primary'>EDITAR</button></a> |
                                    <a href='borrar.php?borrar=1&iden=".$row['id']."'><button type='button' class='btn btn-danger'>BORRAR</button></a>
                                </td>
                        </tr>";
                        $i++;

                    }
                ?>


            </table>    

        </div>
        </div>
        </div>

    </body>



</html>
```

Here is the "connect" file:

```
    <?php

    $con=mysql_connect('localhost','root','root')OR die('error : '.mysql_error());
    $db=mysql_select_db('desafio');

    if($db){
        echo '';

    }else{
        echo 'Error :' .mysql_error(); 
    }


?>
```

But i dont know how should i do it using Codeigniter, i cannot fetch data from tables "materias"and "carreras".I've thought something like this (it is just an example of my Crudmodel):

```
    <?php

    Class Crudmodel extends CI_Model{

        public function getRecords(){
            $query = $this->db->get('materias');

            if($query -> num_rows() > 0){

                return $query->row();
            }

        }

    }


?>
```

Then, here is my controller file:

```
    <?php

    class Home extends CI_Controller{

        public function index(){
            $records = $this->Crudmodel->getRecords();
            $this->load->view('home', ['records'=>$records]);

        }

    }


?>
```

Finally, here is my main file (which should have the information of both tables)

```
    <?php include('header.php'); ?>

<?php include('footer.php'); ?>


    <div class="container"> 
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">

        <h2 align="center">TABLA:MATERIAS</h2>
        <input id="busqueda_tabla" type="text">
            <table class="table table-hover" align="center" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="700" id="tabla_busqueda">
                <thead>
                    <th>id</th>
                    <th>Carrera</th>
                    <th>Nombre</th>
                    <th>Descripcion</th>
                    <th>Carga horaria (hs)</th>
                    <th>Accion</th>
                </thead>


<?php

                $sql=mysql_query("SELECT s.*, c.nombre AS carrera FROM materias s LEFT JOIN carreras c ON s.carrera_id=c.id");
                $i=1;
                    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
                        echo "<tr>
                                <td>".$i."</td>
                                <td>".$row['carrera']."</td>
                                <td>".$row['nombre']."</td>
                                <td>".$row['descripcion']."</td>
                                <td>".$row['carga_horaria']."</td>
                                <td align='center'>
                                    <a href='editar.php?editar=1&iden=".$row['id']."'><button type='button' class='btn btn-primary'>EDITAR</button></a> |
                                    <a href='borrar.php?borrar=1&iden=".$row['id']."'><button type='button' class='btn btn-danger'>BORRAR</button></a>
                                </td>
                        </tr>";
                        $i++;

                    }
                ?>

            </table>

        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
```

Hope you can help me :(

Comment: Couple tips on database https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/configuration.html and view https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html#loading-multiple-views

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  <?php

    Class Crudmodel extends CI_Model{

        public function getRecords(){

            $this->db->select('s.*, c.nombre AS carrera')
                     ->from('materias s')
                     ->join('carreras c', 's.carrera_id = c.id', 'left');
            $q = $this->db->get();

            if($q -> num_rows() > 0){

                return $q->result();
            }

            return false;

        }

    }


?>
```

this?
edit: included manual @
https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html

more edits below:

```
<?php

    class Home extends CI_Controller{

        public function index(){
            $this->load->model('Crudmodel');
            $data['records'] = $this->Crudmodel->getRecords();
            $this->load->view('home', $data['records']);

        }
    }
?>
```

view:

```
  <table>
    <?php
        $i=1;
        foreach($records as $record) {
            // build your table view here
            echo "<tr>
                      <td>".$i."</td>
                      <td>".$record->carrera."</td>
                      <td>".$record->nombre."</td>
                      <td>".$record->descripcion."</td>
                      <td>".$record->carga_horaria."</td>
                      <td align='center'>
                         <a href='editar.php?editar=1&iden=".$record->id."'><button type='button' class='btn btn-primary'>EDITAR</button></a> |
                         <a href='borrar.php?borrar=1&iden=".$record->id."'><button type='button' class='btn btn-danger'>BORRAR</button></a>
                      </td>
                  </tr>";
        }
        $i++;
    ?>
    </table>
```

---

Comment: Thank you for reply!,but take a look at this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43034938/fetching-data-from-tables-using-codeigniter

Comment: I added the basic workings, up to you to generate the table in the view.

Comment: Thank you for reply again!, but i dont get it dude :(.Can help me to show the table like if it was the "old" code.. doing something like this in the view?
https://ideone.com/QvvcXh

Comment: I edited the view a bit more. We use "->" because we are passing an object not an array.

Comment: sry forgot to load model in controller $this->load->model('Crudmodel');

Comment: Mate, you're helping me a lot :), but i still dont get it.. I do not understand where should i put the condition:$sql=mysql_query("SELECT s.*, c.nombre AS carrera FROM materias s LEFT JOIN carreras c ON s.carrera_id=c.id");

Comment: The model Crudmodel does this, just differently with the CodeIgniter Query builder. In your view you do not have to do any queries anymore. The view receives the data from the controller, the controller calls your models. The model calls the database.

Comment: Excuse me dude..this topic is new for me :(,you mean that this is the condition:
https://ideone.com/sCfPEK

Anyway,im sorry but i do not understand what you mean with " // build your table view here".. what should i do?

Comment: I added table tags to the view. It should work like this. Yes, the model makes a query with that special code. Query builder in CodeIgniter. https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html

Comment: Sorry mate, i gonna check this out!

Comment: Mate it is not working, take a look at this:
https://ideone.com/Sr1WOs

https://ideone.com/myNbno

https://ideone.com/RomoVy


https://i.gyazo.com/607303edcd861d0a2257611c925f3e6e.png
https://i.gyazo.com/c5bb77d50315888a375a1e775a5ad68c.png
https://i.gyazo.com/eb9d833bf5d0818db2906ec1447550c0.png

Comment: It comes down to debugging now. var_dump($data['records']);die; inside the controller before loading the view for example.

Comment: Mate,thak you!.
Can you take a look at this?:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43073533/codeigniter-update-delete-issue

Answer (score 1):

well done for choosing CI.

We need to know what errors you are having, on which files and lines, Which parts that don't work, and more details concerning your error..
However, I can give a checklist to troubleshoot.

1. please make sure your connection string/DB configuration is correct.
2. in your model class, have you called $this->load->database(); in the construct method?
3. have you loaded your model in your controller. e.g.: calling
   $this->load->model('Crudmodel'); 
   on your controller construct method?

the easiest step by step would be detailed on this page:
http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/tutorial/news_section.html

Comment: Dude, i just wanna have this code in my CodeIgniter program:
https://ideone.com/CVAbV6

But, i gotta "call" the tables ("materias" and "carreras") before..inthis way:
https://ideone.com/hfF8sG

But i dont know how should i do that :S